# When I try to call my plugin, neo4j says that I need to wrap my call in a transaction

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to write a plugin for neo4j 3.0.0. To test the water, I wrote this really simple method to expose the outgoing degree.

```
public class Utils extends ServerPlugin {
    @PluginTarget(value = Node.class)
    public int outgoingDegree(@Source Node node) {
        return node.getDegree(Direction.OUTGOING);
    }
}
```

Registering the plugin worked flawlessly:

`curl -v http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/`

```
{
  "Utils" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/Utils"
}
```

My little method is there:

`curl -v http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/Utils`

```
{
  "node" : {
    "outgoingDegree" : {
      "extends" : "node",
      "name" : "outgoingDegree",
      "description" : "",
      "parameters" : [ ]
    }
  }
}
```

Amazing. Now when I try to call this method, everything goes downhill:

`url -XPOST -v http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/Utils/node/20/outgoingDegree -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "{  }"`

```
{
  "message" : "The requested operation cannot be performed, because it has to be performed in a transaction. Ensure you are wrapping your operation in the appropriate transaction boilerplate and try again.",
  "exception" : "BridgeNotInTransactionException",
  "fullname" : "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge$BridgeNotInTransactionException",
  "stackTrace" : [ "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.assertInUnterminatedTransaction(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:72)", "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.getTopLevelTransactionBoundToThisThread(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:105)", "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.getKernelTransactionBoundToThisThread(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:113)", "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.ThreadToStatementContextBridge.get(ThreadToStatementContextBridge.java:65)", "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.ClassicCoreSPI.currentStatement(ClassicCoreSPI.java:205)", "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade$$Lambda$76/46581122.get(Unknown Source)", "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.StandardNodeActions.statement(StandardNodeActions.java:56)", "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getDegree(NodeProxy.java:702)", "com.github.denizco.datascience.neo4jplugin.Utils.outgoingDegree(Utils.java:12)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:158)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeNodeExtension(ExtensionService.java:325)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeNodeExtension(ExtensionService.java:184)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:144)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:121)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(CollectUserAgentFilter.java:69)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)" ],
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : "Neo.ClientError.Request.TransactionRequired",
    "message" : "The requested operation cannot be performed, because it has to be performed in a transaction. Ensure you are wrapping your operation in the appropriate transaction boilerplate and try again."
  } ]
}
```

What's going on here? Why do I need to wrap my call in a transaction and how do I do it? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any operation (read or write) in Neo4j requires a transaction. The only exception `graphDb.execute(cypherString)` which creates a transaction under the hoods if not managed explicitly

So wrap your code into:

```
try (Transaction tx=graphDb.beginTx()) {
   // do your stuff
   tx.success();
}
```

However using "server plugins" is pretty much old tech. In Neo4j 3.0 the gold standard is using procedures and use `CALL` to access them from Cypher.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll use procedures.